# 3DS Max Plugin to Blender Plugin

Tags: plugins, blender, 3dsmax

V3D file and i have a 3D studio Max plug-in but i don't have 3DS Max and I was wondering if it might be able to be converted to a Blender plug-in?

PS.if you need the plug-in [click me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQfG2vV_VfvYThFdU8tRExQNE0/view?usp=sharing)

PS.2.the V3D file is a Volition 3D file for the games Red Faction and Summoner by THQ and Volition

Thanks Jared

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

3D Studio plugins are binary libraries that are linked specifically against the 3D Studio application, they cannot be used with other applications.

Blender uses python to add customised features. If you know how the plugin achieves it's results you could create an addon for blender that performs a similar task.

Comment: can the 3ds plugin be decompiled I don't know how it exports the .V3D and if it can be decompiled you might be able make a  Blender plugin?

Comment: If [this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/v3d-viewer/) uses the same v3d file then it would be easier place to start than decompiling.

Comment: i dont know i will try it